# Copy s3 files from one bucket to another using pyspark

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark

I have 2 bucket in S3 with following structure:

Source bucket: s3://leo-source/sales_input

Source files: 
sales_data_Q1_2019.csv, sales_data_Q2_2019.csv, Region.csv, 
product_2019.csv, product_2020.csv

Target bucket:

1. s3://leo-target/sales_output/sales_data
2. s3://leo-target/sales_output/product
3. s3://leo-target/sales_output/Region

Using pyspark dataframe, I want to copy the files from source to target path with similar names, for example all sales_data files come under sales_data folder only.

Thanks

Comment: Why you want to do this using pyspark, if your usecase include moving data only I would suggest go through aws cli?

Comment: Actually, I want to read the files and write it in parquet format and then will do some other joining. The whole code will be implemented then in glue job.

Comment: Have you tried anything and getting error then we can help?